# In Android Marshmallow App is having all dangerous permission by default

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have built an app with android sdk version 22 and now I want to upgrade it with sdk 23. I know that from Android 6.0 onwards user would have to allow or deny dangerous permissions at runtime. But in my case when I compiled my app with sdk 23 and run it on a Android Android 6.0 device(I tried with two devices) I can see the app is not crashing and all the dangerous permissions which are enlisted in Manifest are given by default. Can someone please help me finding out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed TargetSDK to 23?

Android checks the target sdk and loads apis of that target. Here even though you are compiling it to 23, android thinks that Marshmallow apis are not used and hence defaults to previous API. So run time permissions are not checked.